# Incorrect URL format in JSON output via WCF service

Tags: wcf, json, formatting

I have a WCF service contract defined as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
        UriTemplate =
            "HubContent/{language}?apptype={appType}"
        ,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    HubResults GetHubContent(string language, string appType);
```

In the implementation of this contract in the service, I return a List of objects that gets parsed out in JSON. However whenever one of the properties of the objects is a URL or any string that contains forward slashes the JSON that is returned by the service in the browser escapes the forward slashes. So this url:- http://www.example.com/test/site will look like this

```
http\/\/www.example.com\/test\/site.
```

Is there something I need to specify maybe in the contract related to formatting to rectify this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escaping forward slashes is perfectly valid JSON (see http://json.org/ , the "string" construction). If you pass , for example,

```
{"myUrl":"http\/\/www.example.com\/test\/site"}
```

to any JSON parser (e.g. the JavaScript "eval" function), the value of myUrl will be "http://www.example.com/test/site" (it will automatically unescape the slashes).

Or did I misunderstand your question? In this case, can you post an example of JSON that you think is broken?

Comment: Thanks Eugene I was not aware of that. Is there a specific reason as to why there would a default preference of escaping forward slashes ?

Comment: I should know this, since JSON support in WCF was my feature back when I was at Microsoft, but for the life of me I can't remember the exact answer anymore :) If I had to guess, I believe it had to do with the WCF convention for serializing DateTime to JSON, as strange as that sounds.